# ThreeJS FBO Particle Lighting and Shadows

Tags: three.js, glsl, lighting, particle-system, fbo

**Update: I decided to implement a simple lighting solution from this link, http://blog.edankwan.com/post/three-js-advanced-tips-shadow, suggested by ScieCode.  It's the first part of the linked page.  The result can be seen in the picture at the bottom of this post.**

**The linked page does include information on how to cast shadows using a custom shader material in ThreeJS as well, but I feel it's more suited for meshes and basic particle systems.  I'm working with an FBO particle system.**

I have a particle system in place using FBOs.  It's built using shader materials in ThreeJS.  The particles become towering cumulus clouds.  How can I apply lighting and shadows to these particles as if they were one solid mesh?

Below are the last set of shaders that render the particles to the screen:

To be honest, I don't even fully understand how the vertex shader is outputting the positions.  I found this example code and suited it for what I'm doing.  I understand most of it, but the tail end of the vertex shader is fuzzy to me.

Vertex:

```
precision highp float;

attribute vec2 id;
attribute vec3 p_color;
attribute float p_size;

uniform vec2 dimensions;
uniform float size;

uniform sampler2D infoTexture;
uniform sampler2D originalTexture;
uniform sampler2D positionTexture;
uniform sampler2D previousPositionTexture;
uniform sampler2D velocityTexture;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying float life;
varying vec2 vSpeed;
varying float vSize;

float modI(float a,float b) {
    float m=a-floor((a+0.5)/b)*b;
    return floor(m+0.5);
}

const float PI = 3.14159265359;

void main() {

    float size_modifier = 1. * p_size;

    float ptr = id.x;
    float u = modI( ptr, dimensions.x ) / dimensions.x;
    float v = ( ptr / dimensions.x ) / dimensions.y;
    vec2 puv = vec2( u, v );

    vec4 velocity = texture2D( velocityTexture, puv );
    // vSpeed = .1 * ( projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( velocity.xyz, 1. ) ).xy;

    vec4 i = texture2D( infoTexture, puv );

    vec4 prev_pos = texture2D( previousPositionTexture, puv );
    vec4 origin_pos = texture2D( originalTexture, puv );

    vec4 c = texture2D( positionTexture, puv );
    vec3 p = c.xyz;
    vUv = uv;
    float life_time = 1000.;
    life = 1. - ( c.a / life_time );
    // if( c.a == 0. ) life = 0.;

    if( velocity.a != 1. ){

        size_modifier = .0;

    }

    vec4 modified = modelViewMatrix * vec4( p, 1. );
    // float a = -atan( vSpeed.y, vSpeed.x ) - .5 * PI;
    // float l = clamp( length( vSpeed ), .5, 4. );
    // mat2 rot = mat2( cos( a ), -sin( a ), sin( a ), cos( a ) );

    // modified.xyz += size * i.x * 10. * vec3( rot * position.xy, 0. );
    // modified.xyz += size * size_modifier * i.x * 10. * vec3( rot * position.xy, 0. );
    modified.xyz += size * size_modifier * i.x * 10. * vec3( position.xy, 0. );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modified;

}
```

Fragment:

```
precision highp float;

varying float vSize;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying float life;
varying vec2 vSpeed;
varying vec3 p_color_f;

uniform float useTriangles;

const vec2 barycenter = vec2( .5, .6666 );

void main() {

    // render circles
    float d = smoothstep( .5, .55, 1. - 2. * length( vUv - barycenter ) );
    if( d <= 0. ) discard;

    vec3 frag_c = vec3( p_color_f );

    gl_FragColor = vec4( frag_c, 1.);

}
```

How I added the shader chunks to the custom shader:

```
particleMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
        THREE.UniformsLib.shadowmap,
        THREE.UniformsLib.lights,
        THREE.UniformsLib.ambient,
        {
            size: { type: 'f', value: 1 },
            useTriangles: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
            originalTexture: { type: 't', value: texture },
            infoTexture: { type: 't', value: texture2 },
            positionTexture: { type: 't', value: positionSim.fbos[ 0 ] },
            previousPositionTexture: { type: 't', value: positionSim.fbos[ 1 ] },
            velocityTexture: { type: 't', value: velocitySim.fbos[ 1 ] },
            dimensions: { type: 'v2', value: dimensions },
            cameraPosition: { type: 'v3', value: new THREE.Vector3() },
            prevModelViewMatrix: { type: 'm4', value: new THREE.Matrix4() },
            prevProjectionMatrix: { type: 'm4', value: new THREE.Matrix4() }
        } ]),
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'particle-vs' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'particle-fs' ).textContent,
    transparent: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: true,
    lights: true
    // blending: THREE.NoBlending
} );
```

Basic lighting result:
[image]

Even that added a lot of depth to the storm.

Comment: Those are `UniformLibs`, not `ShaderChunks`, they represent extra uniforms that you bind to the shader, they contain information used by the `ShaderChunks`. Chunks are pieces of code that get imported inside the GLSL shader itself, to facilitate the implementation of common things. You use `#include <name_of_chunk>`  inside of your shader to import these. [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_vert.glsl.js)

Comment: OK, I forgot about that, but for my case ( FBO Particles ), I'll just work with simple lighting like you see in the picture.  I'll make it work.  If I was using meshes, I would definitely take the route you suggested in your initial response and I'll clean all this up and mark your reply as the answer because it actually is the answer to what I asked.  Is there a way I can talk to you privately about further development ?

Comment: @sciecode https://discourse.threejs.org is likely the easiest way. Feel free to hit me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear how you want the shadows or lighting to behave. If you could make it more clear, I would gladly edit this response to best answer your questions.

With that being said, there are two resources that could be viable in your case:

- Edan Kwan's [blog post](http://blog.edankwan.com/post/three-js-advanced-tips-shadow) on shadows for custom shaders / particles. It's a bit outdated, but most of it still stands and should give you a decent understanding of the problems your are trying to solve.
- Since some of the GLSL ShaderChunks have changed since the making of Edan's post, I suggest that you take a look at this [discourse post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shadermaterial-particles-not-receiving-shadows/3962) I made, when I was trying something that sounds similar to what you are asking.

In order to simulate correct lighting, you need to import `light_pars` ShaderChunks and all of its dependencies. With that, you can get access to light intensity on each particle vertex position. You can use that information on whichever way you seem fit.

Comment: I can already see your reply is a big help!  I'll look into those links and I understand what you mean about the shader chunks.  As for the behavior, I just want the particle system to be lit like a mesh would be lit, so if there's a column of particles, there would be a dark side and a light side.

Comment: I added my last set of shaders that actually put the particles to the screen.  When I added the shader chunks to these shaders, they stopped working and that doesn't surprise me.  There's no errors, but the particles aren't rendered to the screen anymore.

Comment: If you are correctly including the ShaderChunks, they should either break your code and show an error or work correctly. In order to know how use the shaders correctly you need to analyze them in the source code, there is no documentation for them.

Comment: What can I say?  There's no error codes or warnings in the console and my particles don't render to the screen.  I didn't think they would after injecting "standard" shader chunks into shaders that are using FBOs to render the particles.  Updated my post to reflect how I added the chunks to the shader..

Comment: Well, for lighting.. you can sort of calculate the lighting yourself, just bind a light_position uniform to the particle shader, define a normal vector for each particle, and calculate the dot product to get how much light is touching that particle "surface". Just remember to update this uniform at every frame if light moves over time.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to calculate shadows on my own, but I've followed Edan's blog post, updated that according to what I do on the discourse post I sent you. And everything worked out just fine. On the second link, there are some extra information I link to the shader, called `UniformsLib`. Give those a try and see if something changes. If you make a jsfiddle with only the particle rendering part of your code, I might be able to give you more clues as to what is happening.

Comment: I'm gonna try to implement a basic lighting method like you suggested with the dot product and see how that goes.  I'll update the post with results..